# IIS 6 multiple sites on the same domain, redirection

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, redirect, django

I have a problem with win2k3, iis6 and django. I have a django application which works fine and it is on the root of my domain. say http://domain.com/

What i have to do is to serve this application from http://domain.com/foo/bar/
If this wasn't a django application (eg: asp or php) i would just move my files under wwwroot/foo/bar

The only solution i came up with is this:
I have created two sites, the first is my django application which is served under http://domain.com:8080

The second one has virtual directories foo and bar one inside another like domain/foo/bar and they point to http://domain.com:8080/ *(I have selected "a redirection to URL" from Virtual Directory and checked "The exact URL entered above")*.

This works but the url is not masked so the address bar shows http://domain.com:8080

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way in IIS6 to show a different URL than the folder you're running under is with isapi rewrite: http://www.isapirewrite.com/.  Here's an article on how to do it: http://aspalliance.com/549_ISAPI_Rewrite_